# iOSで左と右のイヤホンから同時に異なる音楽を再生する方法

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

別録りした異なる音源を左と右で同時に再生したいという要望があります。

その方法について調べてみたところ、
OpenALを使うと音源の位置を設定できるようだったので
片方の音源を右へ、もう片方の音源を左へ設置するということを考えたのですが、
OpenALはmp3などの音声再生は対応していないようでした。

mp3などを変換してリニアPCMにすることも可能なようですが、
短いサウンドならまだしも、15分ほどの音源を変換する時間待たなくてはいけないのは
現実的ではありません。

また、OpenALは位置を細かく設定できますが、
今回の用途は左と右から別々の音を出すだけでよく
もっと単純な方法は無いものか探しています。
（Core Audioにはそのような再生方法はなさそう？）

もっと良い方法やアドバイスがありましたら、ご教授頂けますと幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

使ったことはありませんが、
一番簡単そうなのはAVAudioEngineでAVAudioMixerNodeを使うことじゃないでしょうか。
1つ目のInputのpanを左、2つ目のInputのpanを右へ振ります。

CoreAudioでMixerNodeを使っても可能です。

Comment: これで目的が達成できそうです。有難うございました。